# The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value error

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, visual-c#-express-2010

The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value error

I'm trying to enter data into my table using a form, the date formats in both the form validation and the sql server are both dd/mm/yy, however when i try to submit data from the form with a day higher than 12 (e.g. 13/12/2012) it throws an exception whose cause is "The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value error", and if i try to enter data into the form in a mm/dd/yy format it states "wrong date format" which is suppose means that the dd/mm/yy format is the correct format

here's the code for my form below:

```
    private void btnAddProject_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime startDate;
        DateTime endDate;

        if (txtProjectName.Text == "") //client side validation
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter Project Name");
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            startDate = DateTime.Parse(txtProjectStart.Text);
            endDate = DateTime.Parse(txtProjectEnd.Text);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Wrong Date Format");
            return;
        }
        fa.CreateProject(txtProjectName.Text, startDate, endDate, (int)cbCustomers.SelectedValue, ptsUser.Id);
        txtProjectName.Text = "";
        txtProjectStart.Text = "";
        txtProjectEnd.Text = "";
        cbCustomers.SelectedIndex = 0;
        MessageBox.Show("Project Created");
        adminControl.SelectTab(2);
    }// end btnAddProject
```

And this is the code in my DAO:

```
public void CreateProject(string name, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, int customerId, int administratorId)
    {
        string sql;
        SqlConnection cn;
        SqlCommand cmd;
        Guid projectId = Guid.NewGuid();

        sql = "INSERT INTO Project (ProjectId, Name, ExpectedStartDate, ExpectedEndDate, CustomerId, AdministratorId)";
        sql += String.Format("VALUES('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', {4}, {5})", projectId, name, startDate, endDate, customerId, administratorId);

        cn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.WM75ConnectionString);
        cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);

        try
        {
            cn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error Creating Project", ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            cn.Close();
        }

    }//end CreateProject Method
```

This is my code for my facade:

```
public void CreateProject(string name, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, int customerId, int administratorId)
    {
        dao.CreateProject(name, startDate, endDate, customerId, administratorId);
    }//end CreateProject
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Basically, you shouldn't be passing the `DateTime` values as *strings* in your SQL at all. Use parameterized SQL, and just set the parameter value directly. You should *always* use parameterized SQL as far as possible:

- It gives better code/data separation
- It avoids problematic conversions (like this one)
- It avoids SQL injection atttacks

Additionally, your exception handling is pointlessly complex. Just use a `using` statement, and let the `SqlException` bubble up directly - why bother wrapping it in a vanilla `Exception`?

Answer (score 13):

You can do sqldatetime conversion like
 [sqldatetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191120/net-datetime-to-sqldatetime-conversion)

```
 var sqlFormattedDate = myDateTime.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score -2):

```
sql = "INSERT INTO Project (ProjectId, Name, ExpectedStartDate, ExpectedEndDate, CustomerId, AdministratorId)";
sql += String.Format("VALUES('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', {4}, {5})", projectId, name, startDate.toString("dd-MMM-yyyy"), endDate.toString("dd-MMM-yyyy"), customerId, administratorId);
```

A suggestion : why are you using `Insert` statement in your code? You can have a stored procedure instead.

Comment: There's no need to use a stored procedure - or at least, you haven't suggested any benefits that would confer. Just using parameterized SQL  should get rid of this problem.

Comment: The solution is convert the datetime to "dd-MMM-yyyy". 

sql = "INSERT INTO Project (ProjectId, Name, ExpectedStartDate, ExpectedEndDate, CustomerId, AdministratorId)"; sql += String.Format("VALUES('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', {4}, {5})", projectId, name, startDate.toString("dd-MMM-yyyy"), endDate.toString("dd-MMM-yyyy"), customerId, administratorId);

Comment: That's a *bad* solution. A much *better* solution is to avoid unnecessary string conversions.

Comment: then you can use the CulturInfo.

Comment: That's assuming that the database uses the same culture as the system. Why do you want to jump through complicated hoops to create a fragile solution when there's a simple and solution which is cleaner and *works*? Separating parameter values from the SQL is simply good practice - for all types.

Comment: try convert(datetime , startDate , 103) in the insert statement

Comment: Why have a conversion in the first place? There's no need. The source value is a `DateTime`, the target value is for a date-related field. Why make things complicated using strings?