# Getting error while converting a string to datetime format in c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I am getting error "**The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.**" while executing the sqlcommand. The input of date time is "**10/24/2013 06:25:30 PM**"
//C# Code

```
    string sa1 = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
    string fr = textBox1.Text;
    string dt = sa1 + " " + fr;
    string to = textBox2.Text;
    string dt1 = sa1 + " " + to;

    DateTime tim = DateTime.ParseExact(dt.ToString(), "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    DateTime tim1 = DateTime.ParseExact(dt1.ToString(), "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    DateTime tim2 = Convert.ToDateTime(tim);
    DateTime tim3 = Convert.ToDateTime(tim1);
    dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=173.83.250.71,1433; Network Library=DBMSSOCN; Initial Catalog=paradigm;User Id=sa; password=Paradigm123");
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into paradigm.dbo.driverotcalc ( emp_no, fro, too, purpose, totalhrs, entdate, amount) values('" + emp.ToString() + "','" + tim2.ToString() + "','" + tim3.ToString() + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "','" + DateTime.Now + "','" + textBox5.Text + "')",con);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Can any one help me in resolving this issue.

Comment: Your DB is probably expecting dd/MM/yyyy dates, so 24 is not a valid month.

Comment: You would be better off using a parametized query.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542510/how-do-i-create-a-parameterized-sql-query-why-should-i/542545#542545 on how to create a parameterized query

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12393665/the-conversion-of-a-varchar-data-type-to-a-datetime-data-type-resulted-in-an-out

Comment: What database engine is it?  Is it Sql Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You insert DateTime.Now. I suspect the format is not the same as the date format in your database.
Try :

```
string formatDB ="YYYY/MM/dd";
DateTime.Now.ToString(formatDB);
```

Replace formatDB by your date format in your database