# Error when saving datetime to a SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

I'm doing a bit of C# Winforms coding in my spare time, just getting to grips with everything. I have a SQL script which creates a local db on vs2012 as follows:

```
-- Creating table 'Users'--
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users]
(
    [UserID] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Surname] nvarchar(30)  NOT NULL,
    [Forename] nvarchar(30)  NOT NULL,
    [Company] nvarchar (30) NOT NULL,
    [SecurityLevel] int NOT NULL,
    [IssueDate] DateTime  NOT NULL,
    [ExpiryDate] DateTime  NOT NULL,
    [CardID] int NOT NULL,
);
GO
```

Now I want to save details to that table, so I created a method:

```
  private void btnSaveDetails_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
        SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
        sc.ConnectionString = (Properties.Settings.Default.BioEngineering);
        sc.Open();
        com.Connection = sc;
        com.CommandText = ("INSERT INTO Users (Forename, Surname, Company, SecurityLevel, IssueDate, ExpiryDate, CardID) VALUES ('" + this.txtFirstName.Text + "','" + this.txtLastName.Text + "','" + this.txtCompany.Text + "','" + this.cboSecurityLevel.Text + "','" + this.dtpIssueDate.Value + "','" + this.dtpExpiryDate.Value + "','" + this.cboCardID.Text + "');");

        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sc.Close();
    }
```

When I run the code I get an error

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

I know it has something to do with the datetime format of either the SQL or C# equivalent but I don't know how to format the datetime in order to comply to the error. Any ideas? I tried formatting it withing the Command Text line but it didn't seem to resolve the issue.

Comment: You should use Parameterized Queries. Not just that, but part of your issue is .Value, SQL expects the DateTime in format: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff" depending on column type. Also, DateTime2 is more appropriate for the SQL column type.

Comment: Not should, must.  Your problem looks less to be a code problem and more to be a data problem.  What are the values you are putting in?

Comment: the datetime values come from a datepicker box

Comment: @EBrown You are right about the parameterized queries, but you could have stopped there.  The string coercion and expected format is irrelevant once OP moves to proper parameter usage.

Comment: thanks for letting me know about parameterized Queries @EBrown. As i say im getting to grips with things so sorry for the novice mistake of allowing sql attacks.

Comment: DateTime Format is important while casting, example : today french datetime compared to today us date time is not the same string but the same date.

Comment: @MacKentoch That's a display issue, not related to storing the data.  A date is a date, as you say.

Comment: goldeneye Read this, please: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx Your utilization of DateTimePicker.Value casts it to the default, localized, SQL-unrepresentable string. As @DonBoitnott and I have said, switching to Parameterized Queries will not only fix this problem, but remove a plethora of SQL injection attacks that anyone could execute on your code as it stands now. Also: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738521%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: @EBrown thank you very much for pointing me on the right path!

Comment: possible duplicate of [The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12393665/the-conversion-of-a-varchar-data-type-to-a-datetime-data-type-resulted-in-an-out)

Answer (score 0):

Datepicker.Value is returned as

```
[Your_System_Short_Date_Format] + [Space] + [Your_System_Long_Time_Format]
```

I don't know why in this format but just found when checked with the Default Long Format while adding the DateTimePicker.

So you are passing a value depending upon you system [Regional/Calendar] settings where the SQL engine expects to be in a format like EBrown said

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff
```

So if you surely want to Concatenate then you can use like

```
 command.CommandText = 
    "INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES(DateOfBirth) VALUES ('" +
     dtpDateOfBirth.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "')";
```

But i truly recommend you to keep a practice of using parameters from the beginning itself. Or else after making a huge application, you might need to walk back to change those concatenations to Parameters.

It is simple like

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES(DateOfBirth) VALUES (@dob)";

command.Parameters.Add("@dob", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dtpDateOfBirth.Value;

     // Or Simply

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", dtpDateOfBirth.Value);
```

You can add more parameters with different Data Types using parameters. The SqlCommand class safely converts those to an SqlCommand especially from Injection Attacks.

Answer (score -4):

First of all, the way you did is very crude way of running sql statements that is prone to lots of errors, memory leaks, sql injection attacks, and security issues.

--You should use `using` statement to dispose connection & command objects, better error handling.

-- you should use parameterized queries or stored procs or ORMs like nhibernate or EF.

Anyway error in your code is as follows

convert date fields to this format `.ToString("MM/dd/YYYY")`

```
 private void btnSaveDetails_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
        sc.ConnectionString = (Properties.Settings.Default.BioEngineering);
        sc.Open();
        com.Connection = sc;
        com.CommandText = ("INSERT INTO Users (Forename, Surname, Company, SecurityLevel, IssueDate, ExpiryDate, CardID) VALUES ('" + this.txtFirstName.Text + "','" + this.txtLastName.Text + "','" + this.txtCompany.Text + "','" + this.cboSecurityLevel.Text + "','" + this.dtpIssueDate.Value.ToString("MM/dd/YYYY") + "','" + this.dtpExpiryDate.Value.ToString("MM/dd/YYYY") + "','" + this.cboCardID.Text + "');");

        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sc.Close();
    }
```

Comment: I know man, ORM, Stored procs , Parameterized quries, lots of options...one step a time for him, let him get a feel of it first :).  you guys too serious man, want to teach him best practices in 101 class.

Comment: wow, and you think learn to code is similar to going to doctor for illness

Comment: I can find issue with every line of code in the question man, and we are not correcting every one of them.

Comment: and using statement around command /connection objects, writing a separate service for all database calls,and may be inject it through dependency injection into the form etc..

Comment: Finding other flaws in code is common.  A complete answer fleshes out those problems as well in clear concise ways.