# Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1 The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Tags: c#-4.0

```
insert into book_issues(stu_id,stu_name,book_id,book_title,
user_type,issu_date,exect_return_date,is_return) 
values
( 5,'thenmozhi',10,'windows programming', 
'Student','10-10-2015 16:23:55','15-10-2015 16:23:55','False');
```

I receive error for this code, kindly tell me my fault...

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do this way.
always  try the parameterized way.

like :  `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datecreation", Convert.ToDateTime(datecreation));`

Check here:
[The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12393665/the-conversion-of-a-varchar-data-type-to-a-datetime-data-type-resulted-in-an-out)

You could do something like this:

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Connectionstring"))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
{
    string sql = "insert into Usertable ";
    sql += "values(@mVendid, @usrname, @usrpass, @datecreation, @createdby)";
    cmd.CommandText = sql;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mVendid", mVendid);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usrname", username);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usrpass", userpass);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datecreation", Convert.ToDateTime(datecreation));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@createdby", createdby);
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Just change this as per your code.

Comment: What kind of help you need.?

Comment: You can get a lot of books for free on online once search for ado.net. Give them a look.