# DateTime format to SQL format using C#

Tags: c#, sql, datetime

I am trying to save the current date time format from C# and convert it to an SQL Server date format like so `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` so I can use it for my `UPDATE` query.

This was my first code:

```
DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.Now;
string sqlFormattedDate = myDateTime.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

The output on date is okay, but time is always "12:00:00" so I changed my code to the following:

```
string sqlFormattedDate = myDateTime.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + " " + 
myDateTime.TimeOfDay.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

It gave me this compile error:

> FormatException was unhandled

And suggested I need to parse. So I tried doing this to my code as per my research here in StackOverflow:

```
string sqlFormattedDate = myDateTime.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + " " + 
myDateTime.Parse.TimeOfDay.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

or

```
string sqlFormattedDate = myDateTime.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + " " + 
myDateTime.tryParse.TimeOfDay.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

But it's telling me that it's a method which is not valid for given context. I tried searching for solutions to my problem and I have been stuck for two hours now. I'm still a bit new in C#, can you help me please?

Comment: Have you looked at DateTime.TryParseExact?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191120/net-datetime-to-sqldatetime-conversion

Comment: Why not use a parameter to update the `DateTime` or are you storing it as a string ? Also `ToString` on `Date` would imply that time is always `12:00:00`

Comment: You should use a **parametrized query** with a parameter of type `DATETIME` and then you could avoid doing all this converting back and forth to and from a string representation!

Comment: As others have said, using parameters and just keeping everything as a `datetime` would be a good start. Even better, why are you passing the server the *current* time - it has a `GETDATE()` function that can be called entirely on the server side.

Answer (score 302, accepted):

try this below

```
DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.Now;
string sqlFormattedDate = myDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
```

Comment: thank you very much i was trying string sqlFormattedDate = myDateTime.DateTime... for some reason this is what i wanna achieve.

Comment: My search in stackoverflow keeps referring me to a wrong reference although the question had been answer several times, newbies like me can't relate because of this. Sorry to All, I'll close the question as soon as I am able.

Comment: I think the C# "Sortable" format does the same thing. So you can just do myDateTime.ToString("s");

Comment: @ProVega it doesn't look the same (.ToString('s') has a T instead of a space between date and time) - but I can confirm that they're parsed the same by SQL server with or without the T (I'm on 2012). I've started using 's' as my logging datetime format, so I'll go with that I think, thanks!

Comment: Yeah, on the official page [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql), they use the name "ODBC canonical" for the form with a space separating `yyyy-MM-dd` from the time of day, and the name "ISO8601" for the form where the separating character is a `T`. But yes, both forms convert implicitly (and correctly) to a `datetime`.

Comment: Use `myDateTime.ToString("o");` instead, it has more percision than this answer and is literally described as "Round-trip date/time pattern" in the docs. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: 1000% works in c#

Comment: In newer versions of .Net you can achieve the same like this:
`myDateTime.StartDate:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`

Answer (score 59):

Using the standard datetime format "s" will also ensure internationalization compatibility (MM/dd versus dd/MM):

```
myDateTime.ToString("s");

=> 2013-12-31T00:00:00
```

Complete Options: (code: sample result)

```
d: 6/15/2008 
D: Sunday, June 15, 2008 
f: Sunday, June 15, 2008 9:15 PM 
F: Sunday, June 15, 2008 9:15:07 PM 
g: 6/15/2008 9:15 PM 
G: 6/15/2008 9:15:07 PM 
m: June 15 
o: 2008-06-15T21:15:07.0000000 
R: Sun, 15 Jun 2008 21:15:07 GMT 
s: 2008-06-15T21:15:07 
t: 9:15 PM 
T: 9:15:07 PM 
u: 2008-06-15 21:15:07Z 
U: Monday, June 16, 2008 4:15:07 AM 
y: June, 2008 

'h:mm:ss.ff t': 9:15:07.00 P 
'd MMM yyyy': 15 Jun 2008 
'HH:mm:ss.f': 21:15:07.0 
'dd MMM HH:mm:ss': 15 Jun 21:15:07 
'\Mon\t\h\: M': Month: 6 
'HH:mm:ss.ffffzzz': 21:15:07.0000-07:00
```

Supported in .NET Framework: 4.6, 4.5, 4, 3.5, 3.0, 2.0, 1.1, 1.0
Reference: [`DateTime.ToString` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: This is not fine-grained enough (misses the milliseconds) and will get you into trouble in queries that rely on ordering by date.

Comment: To get hours and minutes as well, you can use this conversion: **string sqlFormattedDate = YourDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);**

Comment: Use `myDateTime.ToString("o");` instead, it has milliseconds and is literally described as "Round-trip date/time pattern" in the docs. `"s"` is only described as "Sortable date/time pattern" so I wouldn't suggest using it for this. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings

Answer (score 13):

Let's use the built in SqlDateTime class

```
new SqlDateTime(DateTime.Now).ToSqlString()
```

But still need to check for null values. This will throw overflow exception

```
new SqlDateTime(DateTime.MinValue).ToSqlString()
```

`SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.`

Comment: I would prefer if this solution worked for me, but I get "the conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value" error when using it, so I had to resort to the .ToString() solution.

Comment: Interesting, I want to try it, can you add your code with input date value you used?

Answer (score 11):

The correct answer was already given "use parameters". Formatting a date and passing it as a string to SQL-Server can lead to errors as it depends on the settings how the date is interpreted on the server side. In europe, we write '1.12.2012' to indicate december 1st 2012, whereas in other countries this might be treated as january 12th.

When issuing statements directly in SSMS I use the format `yyyymmdd` which seem to be quite general. I did not encounter any problems on the various installations I worked on so far.

There is another seldom used format, which is a bit weird but works for all versions:

```
select { d '2013-10-01' }
```

will return the first of october 2013.

```
select { ts '2013-10-01 13:45:01' }
```

will return october 1st, 1:45:01 PM

I strongly advice to use parameters and *never* format your own SQL code by pasting together homegrown formatted statement fragments. It is an entry for SQL injection and strange errors (formatting a float value is another potential issue)

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is in the "Date" property that truncates `DateTime` to date only.
You could put the conversion like this:

```
DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.Now;
string sqlFormattedDate = myDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); // <- No Date.ToString()!
```

Answer (score 4):

Your first code will work by doing this

```
DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.Now;
string sqlFormattedDate = myDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); //Remove myDateTime.Date part
```

Answer (score 3):

if you want to store current date in table so you can use

> GETDATE();

or pass this function as a **parameter**

eg. **'update tblname set curdate=GETDATE() where colname=123'**

Comment: It works even better as a default value on the SQL table. Unless you are using a framework that doesn't allow for use of default values.

Answer (score 1):

The Answer i was looking for was:

```
DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.Now;
string sqlFormattedDate = myDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

I've also learned that you can do it this way:

```
DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.Now;
string sqlFormattedDate = myDateTime.ToString(myCountryDateFormat);
```

where myCountryDateFormat can be changed to meet change depending on requirement.

Please note that the tagged "This question may already have an answer here:" has not actually answered the question because as you can see it used a ".Date" instead of omitting it. It's quite confusing for new programmers of .NET

Answer (score 1):

Why not skip the string altogether :

```
SqlDateTime myDateTime = DateTime.Now;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the `Date` property that truncates `DateTime` to date only. You could put the conversion like this:

```
DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.Now;

string sqlFormattedDate = myDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: Thanks.  Just what I was looking for ;)  Surprised  Microsoft did not add a flag or command to do this more briefly.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was the two single quotes missing.

This is the sql I run to the MSSMS:

```
WHERE checktime >= '2019-01-24 15:01:36.000' AND checktime <= '2019-01-25 16:01:36.000'
```

As you can see there are two single quotes, so your codes must be:

```
string sqlFormattedDate = "'" + myDateTime.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + " " + myDateTime.TimeOfDay.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + "'";
```

Use single quotes for every string in MSSQL or even in MySQL. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To reverse ASP.NET date format (dd-mm-yyyy) to SQL format (yyyy-mm-dd), utilize the following code snippet:

**WebForm.aspx**

```
<tr>
    <td>Date of Birth:</td>
    <td><asp:Calendar ID="calenderPicker" runat="server" Visible="false" OnSelectionChanged="calenderPicker_SelectionChanged"></asp:Calendar></td>
    <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
    <td><asp:LinkButton ID="btnDatePick" runat="server" OnClick="btnDatePick_Click">GetDate</asp:LinkButton></td>
</tr>
```

**WebForm.aspx.cs**

```
protected void calenderPicker_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        calenderPicker.Visible = true;
        txtDate.Text = calenderPicker.SelectedDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
```

This line of code takes the selected date from the calenderPicker control, converts it to a string with the desired format "yyyy-MM-dd," and then assigns it to the txtDate textbox. This ensures that the date is formatted in the required SQL format before being processed or stored in the database. The CultureInfo.InvariantCulture parameter ensures consistency in formatting across different cultures.

Answer (score -1):

only you put "T"+DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()+  '2015-02-23'

Comment: first the date XD date + "T" + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()

Answer (score -1):

If you wanna update a table with that DateTime, you can use your SQL string like this example:

```
int fieldId;
DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.Now
string sql = string.Format(@"UPDATE TableName SET DateFieldName='{0}' WHERE FieldID={1}", myDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"), fieldId.ToString());
```

Comment: This question has already been answered and accepted with a more elegant solution. And you're missing a closing `"`.

Answer (score -2):

Another solution to pass DateTime from C# to SQL Server, irrespective of SQL Server language settings

supposedly that your Regional Settings show date as dd.MM.yyyy (German standard '104') then

```
DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.Now;
string sqlServerDate = "CONVERT(date,'"+myDateTime+"',104)";
```

passes the C# datetime variable to SQL Server Date type variable, considering the mapping as per "104" rules . Sql Server date gets yyyy-MM-dd

If your Regional Settings display DateTime differently, then use the appropriate matching from the SQL Server CONVERT Table

see more about Rules: https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/functions/convert.php

Comment: This will just call `ToString()` on the DateTime, which is culture setting specific. If the machine sending this SQL command is using another culture setting than the SQL server, the SQL server could mistake it for something else. Do not do this!
See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=netcore-3.1#System_DateTime_ToString

Answer (score -2):

```
   DateTime date1 = new DateTime();

    date1 = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox1.Text);
    Label1.Text = (date1.ToLongTimeString()); //11:00 AM
    Label2.Text = date1.ToLongDateString(); //Friday, November 1, 2019;
    Label3.Text = date1.ToString();
    Label4.Text = date1.ToShortDateString();
    Label5.Text = date1.ToShortTimeString();
```