# What datatype variable should I use to store time so I can load it in my database

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2013

I have an SQL database that I have to store date and time in the records. I am making a project on Visual Studio and I'm using 2 datetime picker controls to prompt for date and time respectively.

I want to know what kind of variable (or class) I should use to store the time and date so that I can store it in the single datetime record in my database.

Comment: `DateTime` is there.

Answer (score 1):

C# has the DateTime type and TimeSpan for this. TimeSpan is not always the best choice and in many cases its better to just use a DateTime and ignore the date part.

The DateTime Class in C# has a .Date for extracting just the date component and a .Time For the Time part (returning a TimeSpan class)

In SQL you can use DATE and TIME or DATETIME.

You can save a C# DateTime into a DATE,TIME or DATETIME (loosing the part you don't need)

In summary I would suggest using a C# DateTime for the Date and a TimeSpan for the time. And Saving them into SQL as a DATE and a TIME.  But you will need to be carefull with TimeSpan as the TimeSpan Is not 100% comparable with SQLs TIME. A TimeSpan in C# can be for more then one day but a time TIME in SQL can only be for one 24 hour period.

Lastly if you have already chosen to use a DATETIME in SQL then why dont you just use a DateTime in C# you can merge the Date And Time thet you get from the UI into one DateTime and just save that in an SQL DATETIME.

Comment: After chasing the many iterations of this question around for a bit, I did manage to find the one piece they all seem to lack, which is -- doesn't .NET have anything to offer us, here? (It does, as it turns out...)

There is a constructor for the SqlDateTime type that accepts a .NET DateTime as its sole parameter. Why that has not been offered, particularly when the OP often states they are new to .NET -- is a mystery to me

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cxsk2s5e(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.Now;
string sqlFormattedDate = myDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Or for more details : [Similar StackOverFlow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17418258/datetime-format-to-sql-format-using-c-sharp) with a very good solution or [Click here](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=DateTime%20C%23%20to%20sql) to get all solutions for this problem

Comment: Why down vote?? Perfect way of answering such question. Because it will let questioner know that answer to such questions already exist and how they can reach there.

Comment: Not my downvote, but there is absolutely no information why OP should try code you posted (in addition to be unconventional recommendation). If you want to provide links - it is customary to add summary of each link (or at very least readable reason why one should check it, "here" is not good explanation).

Comment: Thanks @AlexeiLevenkov I will make an edit to the answer and hope it will be better :)