# C# Generate Query to Compare DateTime with SQL Nvarchar date Column

Tags: c#, sql

I tried to get result depending on two dates which the user checked.
I have two datetimepicker controls.
I want the user to chooses the "from" date and "to" date,
then the query get specific result.

leaving_time column type is nvarchar

This is my query:

```
SELECT name, mil_no, rotba, arrival_time, leaving_time, day, year
FROM dbo.Hodor_data 
WHERE leaving_time BETWEEN '"+dateTimePicker1.Checked.ToString()+ "' AND  '" + dateTimePicker2.Checked.ToString() + '"
```

Where is the mistake?

Comment: Use parameterized queries.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [datetime format to SQL format using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17418258/datetime-format-to-sql-format-using-c-sharp)

Comment: what error are you getting ? If no errors show sample data

Comment: @uno this question diffrent from mine

Comment: @amrkamal If what you need is the DateTime to a formatted SQL query, it's not. `dateTimePicker.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")` is what you're after I guess.

Comment: @amrkamal Show SQL table data and show your entire code for executing this query.

Comment: I have the strong feeling that this _leaving_time_ is not a DateTime column. @amrkamal could you tell us what is the DataType of the column in the database table?

Comment: leaving time in database is not datetime it's ncvarchar(50)

Comment: Then you will have hard time to find dates. Dates should be stored in DateTime columns if you want to have any chance to execute queries on those values.

Comment: but  i think i can compare between two strings if i convert date to string is it true ?

Comment: I don't know how do you store these dates in a varchar column, But to explain the problem suppose that you use a format of dd-MM-yyyy. Now your leaving_time is '01-07-2016' and the two picker values converted to strings are  '15-04-2016' and '15-07-2016'. The leaving_time is not included in this period because alphabetically the letter '0' comes before of '1' . Dates should be used and stored as dates (internally they have a numeric representation that leaves out any possible misunderstanding)

Comment: ok so u mean i must change to datetybe in database ?

Comment: Look, you can do also with a CONVERT as explained below (forgetting to mention that this convert will wreak havoc with indexing), but there is no other correct way to do. Dates should be stored in some kind of DateTime column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checked is a boolean property, and it is not the date. You need to use the Value Property. It is better to add parameters and explicitly specify the type so that the date format conflict is solved.

Edit: If column type in SQL server is `NVARCHAR` and of format `MM/dd/yyyy`, you need to use `ONVERT(DATETIME, leaving_time, 101)`:

```
conn.Open();
SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = 
    new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT name, mil_no, rotba, arrival_time, leaving_time, day, year "
                     + "FROM dbo.Hodor_data where CONVERT(DATETIME, leaving_time, 101) "
                     + "BETWEEN @p1 AND @p2", conn);

SqlParameter fromDate = new SqlParameter("@p1", SqlDbType.DateTime2);
fromDate.Value = dateTimePicker1.Value;
SqlParameter toDate = new SqlParameter("@p2", SqlDbType.DateTime2);
toDate.Value = dateTimePicker2.Value;

dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(fromDate);
dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(toDate);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dataAdapter.Fill(dt);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt; 
conn.Close()
```

You should really consider changing the type of column `leaving_time` to be a DateTime column. This will make your life easier in querying. I can't really see any advantage of storing these values as text.

Comment: @amrkamal can you show the entire code ? which is how you are executing the query and building the command object.

Comment: conn.Open();
 SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT name, mil_no, rotba, arrival_time, leaving_time, day, year FROM dbo.Hodor_data where leaving_time BETWEEN '" + dateTimePicker1.Value + "' AND  '" + dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("") +  "'", conn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dataAdapter.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            conn.Close();

Comment: The name 'dateParamFrom' does not exist in the current context !!

Comment: @amrkamal it will not work if your column type is nvarchar. Can you show a sample values from that column ? is it *2016-07-09* or *09-07-2016* ?

Comment: @amrkamal typo fixed in the answer.

Comment: @amrkamal check the updated code using `CONVERT(DATETIME`

Comment: The variable name '@p1' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.

Comment: @amrkamal add a space after `year` in the query.

Answer (score 3):

You should write parameterized queries and not using string concatenation for passing the parameters, in order to create a sql command. Using string concatenation makes you code vulnerable to sql injections.

```
var cmdText = @"SELECT ...
                FROM dbo.Hodor_data
                WHERE leaving_time BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate";

var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(cmdText, connection);
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", dateTimePicker1.Value);
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDate", dateTimePicker2.Value);
```

where `connection` is your sql connection object.

Comment: Checked is not a DateTime Property .

Comment: That code doesnt use the Checked property, neither should you @user3185569.  Just use the value - its a `DateTime` type

Comment: @user3185569 for this reason I changed it to `Value`. Thanks

Comment: @Plutonix i think the user edited the answer after i posted my comment. Sorry for that.

Comment: @amrkamal could you please debug your code, and check what is the value of `dateTimePicker1.Value` and the value of `dateTimePicker2.Value`? I assume that `leaving_time`'s data type is something like DATETIME. Correct?

Comment: minor typo: `sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@StartDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dateTimePicker1.Value;`

Comment: @Plutonix I had forgotten it :) I would say to change it to `AddWithValue`. Thank you very much for pointing this !

Comment: mistery solved. _leaving_time_ is a nvarchar(50) column. No chance to build correct queries in this condition

Comment: The code above will work when you change the Datatype of _leaving_time_ to DateTime

Comment: @amr can you show a sample value from *leaving_time* column ?

Comment: 6/24/2016  for example

Comment: @amrkamal solved then :) check my edited answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `dateTimePicker1.Text` in  `dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged` event where you are using `dateTimePicker2.Checked` that return `true` or `false` not the value of date