# Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__tblmembe__DD7012648BA5EC8B' When insert in DataBase *** ASP.Net Query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

i create A page for insert users .

but when i run the the page show me this error

[Error Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gN6ZC.png)

ASP Code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["shopDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "insert into tblmember values ('" + txtemail.Text + "','" + txtname.Text + "','" + txtfamily.Text + "','" + txtpass.Text + "','','" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "') ";
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = con;
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
}
```

[My DataBase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4fjL.png)

Comment: It clearly says you are inserting duplicate value into the primary key column.

Comment: Are you trying to insert duplicate entry into the primary key column of datatable?

Comment: What is the Primary key of your table ?

Comment: No . Which duplicate column? There are not duplicate column

Comment: Uid is Primary Key

Comment: Please change your query to a parameterized query unless you want to expose yourself to sql injection attacks.

Comment: What I change My Query?

Comment: You desperately need to read about, understand, and start using parameters. What you have is a textbook example of sql injection.

Comment: you should also check against `this.IsPostBack` unless you want database interaction on `GET`s ... and sql injection galore ... #people

Answer (score 2):

It seems you're not passing the primary key in your query, as the duplicate key is shown as Empty `()`. The Email column `Uid` (*Name is confusing for me*) must be unique. You can't have two rows with the same Primary Key.

Secondly and more important, do not concatenate strings from input to build up your query. This can be easily [injected](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx) with harmful queries that might drop your database.

Check this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38285521/3185569) on how to use parameterized queries.

Comment: i'm Beginner . I do not understand what you mean

Comment: @Kianoush I provided links for this purpose.

Comment: you mean i used the strored procedure ?

Comment: @Kianoush You're not providing a value for column `Uid` which is the identifier for your row. You need to pass a value in your query for `Uid` or update your database table and set it to be auto generated by SQL-Server

Comment: @Kianoush Stored Procedures, Or c# parameters as in this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38285464/c-sharp-generate-query-to-compare-datetime-with-sql-nvarchar-date-column/38285521#38285521

Comment: U id is Email . i can't identifier it

Comment: @Kianoush you're passing the email as empty from your UI ? put a breakpoint on the query line to debug and check what value is inside `txtemail.Text`

Comment: i dont enter value in text box but in database Enter value

Comment: @Kianoush You must specify a value from the UI for the Email since it is the primary key. The Primary key can't be *NULL* and it can't be duplicated in 2 rows.

Comment: this code in pageload . i think put thiis code in button