# Get right datetime format from SQL reader

Tags: c#, sql, datetime, datetime-format, datetimeoffset

Problem: I got SQL database with column of type `datetime` and I am trying to get the value to my c# API variable of type `DateTime`.

```
datetime format in SQL DB:  2011-11-14 00:00:00.000  // So that equals:
                            yyyy - MM - dd HH:mm:ss.ttt
```

Here are some of my attempts to get right value:

```
MyClass.MyProperty= Convert.ToDateTime(reader.GetSqlDateTime(0));
MyClass.MyProperty= Convert.ToDateTime(reader.GetDateTime(0));
MyClass.MyProperty= Convert.ToDateTime(reader.GetValue(0));
MyClass.MyProperty= DateTime.ParseExact(reader.GetValue(0).ToString(), "yyyy - MM - dd HH:mm:ss.ttt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Every time that my attempt compiles without error I get following output:

```
0001-01-01T00:00:00
```

I also tried in combination with `DateTimeOffset` and getting value from DB in string and then converting it to Datetime, but VS

**Update**:

I tried executing my SQL statement on database via server and found out that UserGuid of my profile didn't have any time in selected column. (I used different user credentials when I initially tested SQL statement) I fixed couple of things and debugged a bit more and now connection and reader work as they should. I still have problem with formatting tho.

```
DB value: 2014-08-07 00:00:00.000
Output: 8/7/2014 12:00:00 AM
```

I tried telling it how to format DateTime format with ParseExact, but it throws this exception:

```
System.FormatException' in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

Here is my code for entire reader:

```
        while (reader1.Read())
        {
            newUsagePlan.PlanValidityFrom = DateTime.ParseExact(Convert.ToString(reader1.GetValue(0)), "yyyy - MM - dd HH:mm:ss.ttt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            string lol1 = reader1.GetValue(0).ToString(); // Output: "8/7/2014 12:00:00 AM"
            string lol2 = reader1.GetSqlDateTime(0).ToString(); // Output: "8/7/2014 12:00:00 AM"
        }
```

**FINAL CONCLUSION:**

I solved this problem easily now, by simply using this:

```
string sqlFormattedDate = reader1.GetDateTime(0).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
```

And got desired output: `2014-08-07 00:00:00.000`

One piece of advice: Try not to work on a production and development database in a single project, it can blow your brains out when there are inconsistencies in database data and you are not aware of it. Cheers :)

Comment: What outputs are you getting? is your SQL in the same timezone you are?

Comment: i think your question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17418258/datetime-format-to-sql-format-using-c-sharp

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhz1w05e(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yes, my DB is in same timezone as me. And I always get the same result: 0001-01-01T00:00:00. I tried with different SELECT statements, to get different dates, but that didnt help either. If it helps, my DB Collation is: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS @BugFinder

Comment: Can you put more code in around your reader? so we can see the select etc you're calling, it maybe you're getting a null back - what happens if you run the same query direct in SQL?

Comment: if `reader.GetSqlDateTime(0)` returns a string, then this can convert to a `DateTime` without issue. Your returning value is likely the issue, can you debug and look at the value there?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I am using MS SQL Server, ISS for hosting and MS SQL SMS  for developement.

Comment: I updated my question accordingly after investigating deeper based on your suggestions. @BugFinder