# Error with Datatable.select and DateTime

Tags: c#, sql, datetime, datatable

I have a `Datatable` with a column "Datum" that is `typeof(DateTime)`.

I want to select all rows for the actual month:

```
DataRow[] foundRows = dt.Select("Datum >='" + new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1) + "' AND Datum <='" + new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month)) + "'");
```

I'm getting the error

> Cannot perform '<=' operation on System.String and System.DateTime

If I split the select statement the first one is running well, the second get the same error:

Select 1 is working:
`DataRow[] foundRows1 = dsLinie.Tables[0].Select("Datum >='" + new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1) + "'");`

Select 2 get the error:
`DataRow[] foundRows2 = dsLinie.Tables[0].Select("Datum <='" + new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month)) + "'");`

Why do I get the error, both select statements query the same `DateTime` column "Datum"?

Comment: Replacing the # character by single quote character works OK for me in your first example. Both of your second examples work without change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out. I tried around with the second select and inserted the day manual:

```
DataRow[] foundRows2 = dsLinie.Tables[0].Select("Datum <='" + new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month,1)) + "'");
```

This works until the day is not bigger than 12. So it has to be something with the format of the date between c# and sql. 
Found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20876320/3442153) for my problem:

Using the standard datetime format "s" will also ensure internationalization compatibility (MM/dd versus dd/MM):

`myDateTime.ToString("s");`

=> 2013-12-31T00:00:00

Complete working statement:

`DataRow[] foundRows = dt.Select("Datum >='" + new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1).ToString("s") + "' AND Datum <='" + new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month)).ToString("s") + "'");`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, why the first is working and the second is not, but did you try to put the dates between # AND to explicitly cast the datetime-values to string?

```
DataRow[] foundRows = dt.Select("Datum >=#" + new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1).ToString() + "# AND Datum <=#" + new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month)).ToString() + "#");
```