# How to add parameters in a SQL select query?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

How to add parameters in a SQL select query?

```
string time = 2013-09-25 00:00:00;
```

I wish to use the `time` variable in the below mentioned SQL query

```
Select LastUpdated from Employee where LastUpdated > time;
```

Comment: Pass it in as a parameter with a `datetime` data type.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why the variable is of type `string` and not of type `DateTime` or `DateTimeOffset`?

Comment: why GetUpdatedTime() returns string. change it to return DateTime. Don't bother to convert here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DateTime format to SQL format using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17418258/datetime-format-to-sql-format-using-c-sharp)

Comment: @SherazAhmed That link is for converting datetime to string, I think you haven't understood the at all.

Comment: @KlausGütter That's a part of the existing code and the string variable is used multiple times, I'm just trying to add a new feature so I wish to have the conversion from string to datetime.

Comment: Please let me know why you people are down voting this question so that next time I can improve

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks a lot for your suggestion. I was trying my hands on on a C#(new to me) project so couldn't figure out what exactly you meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just framed my question in a wrong, the query remains the same though. I just wanted `time` to be added as a paramter in my SQL-query. The code for the same looks like

```
String commandText = "Select LastUpdated from Employee where LastUpdated > :time;";
OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(commandText, connection);
command.Parameters.Add("time", time);
```

Thanks a lot for your help!
My bad that I couldn't frame the question properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string sqlDate = time.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
```

Comment: Kindly have a look at the question once again, your answer is no where close to what the question is.

Comment: @m_alpha, Help me understand it then.

string time = GetUpdatedTime();
time = 2013-09-25 00:00:00

is this C# code or SQL ?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your string in C# code to DateTime using
`DateTime.TryParse()` or `Convert.ToDateTime()`

OR

Convert VARCHAR to DATETIME in SQL using
`Convert(datetime, time)`

Answer (score 0):

It appears what the OP is asking is how to convert a `VARCHAR` to a `DATETIME` in SQL Server not actually a `String` to `DateTime` in C#.

You will need to use the following to convert to a `DATETIME`:

```
SELECT LastUpdated 
FROM Employee 
WHERE LastUpdated > CONVERT(datetime, varTime, 121);
```

See the following [MS Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for more information.

To echo others though, you should just pass the parameter in as a datetime and let the database provider factory handle the conversion of appropriate types, or add a new method that actually returns a `DateTime`. In the future, I wouldn't name a method `GetUpdateTime` unless it actually returns a type of `Time`.

Comment: Hi, I tried the same i.e `CONVERT(datetime, varTime, 121)` but compiler in this case assumes `varTime ` as a column in the bd and thus throws error. In my case I have varTime as a variable of type string in C# code and I wish to use the value of that variable to be used in my SQL query. i.e In `CONVERT(datetime, varTime, 121)`  I want the value of variable `varTime` to be converted to type datetime.

Comment: @m_alpha How are you preparing/executing your query within your C# application? Can you provide the code as an edit to your question, and let me know when you have?