# How to convert a .NET DateTime to SQL Datetime?

Tags: sql, .net

I would like to change the `DateTime` format from asp.net format to SQL `Datetime` using if statement. How can I do this ?

```cs
 public DateTime AvailableSince
{
    get
    {
        return _availableSince;
    }
    set
    {
        _availableSince = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DateTime format to SQL format using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17418258/datetime-format-to-sql-format-using-c-sharp)

Comment: Could you give more details about what you mean by "SQL Datetime"? You can use `DateTime` values directly as parameters in `SqlCommand`, which is almost always the right way to go. (If you're talking about converting to a specific text format, I'd strongly advise against using that *when talking to the database*.)

Comment: Neither .Net not SQL (any flavor) store DateTime in a "format", both use some binary value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.Now;
string sqlFormattedDate = myDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
```

Comment: I'm not convinced this is a good idea anyway for what the OP wants to do, but it's definitely worth specifying the invariant culture. Using this in a culture with a non-Gregorian default calendar will give results which would surprise most developers.