# c# asp.net compare dates in where clause in sql query

Tags: c#, asp.net

I tried comparing using the below codes but it failed to work. Did I do the wrong way to compare datetime?
The data type in my sql table is datetime for both Premium_StartDate and Premium_EndDate.
Please help, thanks

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM UserPremiumPeriod WHERE Premium_Username = '" + Session["username"] + "' AND Premium_StartDate <= '" + DateTime.Now + "' AND Premium_EndDate >= '" + DateTime.Now + "' ", con);
```

Comment: Do you get an error? Which one? Maybe you need to [format DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17418258/1997232) so that your sql server able to understand it?

Comment: `'" + Session["username"] + "'`. Do not do that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection And do the same for the dates - don't pass them as strings - pass them as parameters.

Comment: @mjwills then how i do so?

Comment: @Sinatr Most people who suggest SQL Server date formats neglect to test with servers where the date format is YDM. Hilarity often ensues.

Comment: `then how i do so?` Did you read the link?

Comment: @mjwills, dates or similar things don't pose much of threat. Though I agree on consistancy to use params. And it may actually solve OP issue.

Comment: @Sinatr `dates or similar things don't pose much of threat.` Many people suggest date formats (like YYYY/MM/DD) that don't work reliably. So it is a threat in the sense of "it doesn't necessarily work". `And it may actually solve OP issue.` It will _definitely_ solve it.

Comment: @mjwills yes i did, but how do I compare more or less than?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM UserPremiumPeriod WHERE Premium_Username = @Username AND Premium_StartDate <= @Now AND Premium_EndDate >= @Now` is the SQL. The duplicate shows you how to pass the two parameters needed.

Comment: @mjwills i think it worked, thank you !