# How to bind DBnull values to grid view?

Tags: c#-4.0, gridview, dbnull

I am facing struggle to bind values to grid which are retrieved from data base.  I have a database column of type DateTime which is nullable. So, when I am trying to bind that null value, it is throwing an error while adding those column value to object property . So, before adding values fetched from database, i am using a function that converts the value to its default type before adding to object. Since , the default value for datetime Type is 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM . So, where ever null values are present , I am getting this value for this field.

How to solve this issue? Please give your sugesstions.

To explain my scenario , i am adding a piece of code here.

```
public static T GetValue<T>(object o)
{
    T val = default(T);

    if (o != null && o != DBNull.Value)
    {
        val = (T)o;
    }
    return val;
}
```

This is the helper function I am using while reading data from the data reader.

Comment: The default value for datetime is different in SQL and .net.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191120/net-datetime-to-sqldatetime-conversion

Comment: Use a nullable datetime:  `DateTime?`.  In the case of DBNull.Value set it the field to `null`, else, use its value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you declared datetime as nullable, instead of converting it to datetime,convert it by using `datetime?`

Thus it allows datetime values with `null` values