# C# Datetime Issue to Sql

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on C# SQL.

I've a datetime value `"1/10/2016 12:00:00 AM"`
for eg

```
Datetime dt="1/10/2016 12:00:00 AM"
```

When I passed this value to SQL stored procedure as parameter, it changed to `10 Jan 2016`

I need the result as `1 OCT 2016` in SQL. Sql stored procedure parameter data type is datetime.

Many Thanks

Comment: can u show the code. How you are storing it in `dt` and how the SQLParameter looks like

Comment: Sounds you're passing it as string, you should pass it as datetime

Comment: Please take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191120/net-datetime-to-sqldatetime-conversion).

Comment: If passing as a string, format it `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` to ensure it's correctly interpreted.  Sending as  `dd/MM/...` can easiily be interpreted as 'MM/dd/...' if your database language is `en-US` instead of `en-GB`.  The other option's to set your database language; but I prefer the first method since this works regardless.

Answer (score 1):

Change the datetime value and see what happened. If still coming the 10 Jan 2016, then it may be changes that stored procedure is taking the default value which is store value is 10 Jan 2016.

Comment: I know Zohar Peled. But as per the stackoverflow rules we can't do comment if we are below 50 reputation. So for this limit I want to as a answer not a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Use parameters to pass the values to sql query. Or use `myDateTime.ToString("s");` this for datetime value

"s" - Standard datetime format

Answer (score 0):

Well, are you sure that the value in c# is in fact `1 OCT 2016` and not `10 Jan 2016`?
The row:

```
Datetime dt = "1/10/2016 12:00:00 AM";
```

Doesn't even compile.

Best practice for passing `DateTime` values between c# and Sql Server is using sql parameters of type `DateTime` or `DateTime2` and passing an instance of the `DateTime` struct.
If you are doing that, then the DateTime values are guaranteed to pass correctly.